# ASP.NET ListView: how to insert "particular" item each N items?

Tags: asp.net, listview

i would like to do a "weird" thing with the asp.net listview control.

I would like to insert advertising each 8-10 item of the listview (databounded with a database table) : for example each 8-10 item insert the google adwords jscript code.

I've googoled but i haven't found anything. 
Someone know if it's possible to "tell the listview: each 8 items, show this item (google jscript code).

Excuse me for my poor english. 
Hope to be explained, thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can achieve this effect by grouping your items.  You'll need the following:

- a LayoutTemplate in your ListView that contains the groupPlaceholder
- a GroupTemplate in your ListView that contains the itemPlaceholder
- a GroupSeparatorTemplate that contains your ad stuff
- an ItemTemplate that contains the databound stuff

then, you can set your GroupSize to whatever you want and ASP.Net will automatically insert a separator between each group.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(int i = 0; i < limit; i++) {
    if(i % 8 == 0) addSpecialColumn();
}
```

Hope this helps.

[Here's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm) some theory.